# integration between Hive and Hbase

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, hive

I'm using hive over hbase to make some BI.
i have already configured hive and hbase but when i run that query "select count(*) from hbase_table_2 " on Hive

hbase_table_2 is a table in hive which refer to a table in Hbase

This exception occurred:

```
# of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201212171838_0009_m_000000" 

java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation@7d858aa0 closed
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)"

WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect

WARN org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf: hive-site.xml not found on CLASSPATH
```

I don't know where is the problem, can any one help me?

Comment: It seems the error is due to hive-site.xml could not be found in the CLASSPATH. Have you tried to append the location of hive-site.xml to your CLASSPATH and check if that solves the issue?