# Hive integration with mysql

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, hive, derby

i already installed Hive with hadoop over Hbase, i changed the configuration of database driver from derby to  `MySQL`, but i got this exception

```
 FAILED: Error in metadata: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Access denied for user 'DBAUSER'@'linux-96' (using password: YES)
```

NestedThrowables:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'DBAUSER'@'linux-96' (using password: YES)
 FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

i already installed MySQL on localhost and configured `hive-site.xml` to read from this db

i don't know where is the problem, could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is question is mostly related to your MySQL configuration.

I bet that the problem is in your jdbc URL configuration. The error says is trying to connect to host *linux-96* and you mentioned you have installed your MySQL server in your *localhost*.

First run MySQL server in your localhost and try to open a client session:

```
$ sudo service mysqld start
$ mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

You should be able to login (if not search for how to reset MySQL root password)

Create your destination database in MySQL and a user and a password and check you can log in by command line before going ahead.

```
$ mysql -h localhost -u <user> -p<password> <database>
```

Then check you `hive-site.xml` configuration. You should have something like this:

```
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>user</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>password</value>
</property>
```

Comment: done, if you please i faced another problems ,if you can help
that's one of my problems:-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929471/integration-between-hive-and-hbase

Comment: Thank you. I've never used Hive but I'll take a look at your question.

Comment: I am trying to configure mysql with hive from a very very long time, Everytime I encounter errors I don't understand where I am going wrong ..... as you can see in this link gist.github.com/anonymous/bb86629116891e5b2d8c30b95aca9aee hive-site.xml configuration can be seen here in the link gist.github.com/anonymous/44f1c9fc214136a113067cf3b4b72794 Here is file-structure gist.github.com/anonymous/e02b3631da940dfae880252ca72107de

Answer (score 0):

Error strictly says, that you need to add necessary permissions to MySQL table.

Read more about MySQL permissions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html
Here is useful tutorial: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/788/HOWTO%3A+GRANT+privileges+in+MySQL#dv

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql password has changed. This is the only reason.

I have the same error, because my workmate changed mysql password without a word